# Very simple calculation of integral

Tags: calculus, integration

> $$\int_{0}^{1}x(1-x^2)^ndx=\frac{1}{2n+2}$$
>   The book says a simple calculation shows this,but I don't know how to calculate. Maybe it's not simple for me...

Please anyone help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $u=1-x^2$. Then $du=-2x\,dx$, and you basically end up integrating $u^n$.

I expect you can now push things through. Please indicate if there is any difficulty.

Comment: Thank you very much! I calculated and got the answer!

Answer (score 0):

actually, it is connected to the Beta function

Comment: ...or elaborate a bit what you mean...